# How to troubleshoot Error: Could not find package root?

Tags: r, devtools

I am running the command: `devtools::use_testthat()`

and I get the error:

> Error: Could not find package root.

[image]

Why this happens?

Comment: Are you creating your own package? What commands did you run before to initialize your package? What's in your current working directory?

Comment: Yes! working directory that was it. I went one level deeper and now it works; not sure why... thanks!

Answer (score 8):

`devtools` appears now to require the user to `setwd("~/path/to/package")`, even if functions like `devtools::release()` have the `pkg=` parameter set correctly.

Answer (score 4):

My problem was very similar, but running `devtools::document(setwd(...))`. The only thing that worked for me:

1. I copied the DESCRIPTION file from another package (https://github.com/filipezabala/voice);
2. I ran `devtools::document(setwd(...))` again;
3. After that, I edited the DESCRIPTION file and ran again `devtools::document(setwd(...))`.