# Unable to install usethat?

Tags: r

Not sure why i am getting this error. I also set the working directly per suggested in the below link 
[How to troubleshoot Error: Could not find package root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52670051/how-to-troubleshoot-error-could-not-find-package-root)

```
devtools::uses_testthat()
Error: Could not find package root.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no R package `usethat`. There is [`usethis`](https://usethis.r-lib.org/) , which you can install with `install.packages`. There is also a package called `testthat` installable the same way. The command above you are trying to execute is about running tests in a package. I am guessing that is not what you want to do.

See also: [How to troubleshoot Error: Could not find package root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52670051/how-to-troubleshoot-error-could-not-find-package-root)